# How to find the value of the n-th differential value of a function?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

```
def differentiate(fn,lvl,value):
    d=0.0000001
    if lvl==0:
        return fn(value)
    else:
        return (differentiate(fn,lvl-1,value+d)-differentiate(fn,lvl-1,value))/d
def i(x):
    return 1 + x + x**2 + x**3 + x**4 +x**5+x**6
```

I'm trying to find i(lvl)(0), where lvl is the number of times i is differentiated. Im not sure why my code give a totally different output for different d. Will appretiate any help:)

for example,

```
for x in range(7):
    print(differentiate(i,x,0))
```

I expect to get: 1,1,2,6,24,120,720.
However, i'm getting different values depending on the value of d.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and focus on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to increase the likelihood of getting your question answered. Currently, it is unclear and not reproducible.

Comment: You're probably running into [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).

Comment: Could you approach this analytically instead of numerically?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is easy to understand.

You are evaluating values such as `f(0 + d)`, i.e.

```
1 + 0.0000001 + 0.0000001² + 0.0000001³ + 0.0000001^4 + 5 0.0000001^5 = 
1.00000010000001000000100000010000005
```

when double-precision floats are able to represent about 15 significant digits.

Numerical derivatives of a high order are quite challenging.